# How to classify channel, source, and medium from downloaded analytics data the same way GA shows it?

Tags: google, google-analytics

I am trying classify Channel and Source/Medium from Original Data into Channel and Source/Medium as Dashboard of Google Analysis

It means that:

1. I exported Original Data from Google Analytics.
2. I wanna classify this Source/Medium into specific group the same as Google Analysis Dashboard shows it.

Notes: original data is detail with each source and each medium. Besides, Dashboard show Source/Medium by any principle.

Is there any principle to classify this Source/Medium? For example, in the columns "digital_source" there are "mailjet", "mailjet1008" it is grouped with general name "email"

Comment: Are you specifically talking about creating a custom Dashboard with specific data within Google Analytics? Or are you talking about importing data from other sources into Analytics?

Comment: Do you mean you want to take the source/medium data and assign the same channels as GA would? This may help: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3297892?hl=en